# Object with data attributes passed into component as prop isn't kebap-cased by Vue

Tags: javascript, html, object, vue.js, vue-component

https://jsfiddle.net/snLxa8g1/
I'm passing an object as a prop to a component which then uses v-bind to insert all of the key-value pairs as attributes into a div element. In this example snippet, I pass `{ dataXyz: 'hey' }`, which is then rendered lower-case in the DOM. How can I instead convert this CamelCase object notation to kebap-case with Vue (e.g. the attributes key becomes `data-xyz` in the dom)? Is there a Vue-specific helper function/method to accomplish this? The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) shortly mention Camel- and kebap-casing, but don't talk about any way I can convert the passed object to arrive as described :/

Comment: i this [video](https://youtu.be/7YZ5DwlLSt8?t=382) a core team member explains the good practices about Vue, he is using `lodash` methods like kebabcase

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I'd rather not like to import a whole library just to use kebapcase conversion ;)

Comment: your use case not clear enough, do you want to know how do vue accomplish that or you want to do this by yourself ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Have a look at the fiddle. I'm trying to set a `data-` attribute with vue by passing an object to an component. Since I can't use kebap-case in objects, I have to use CamelCase, which in return doesn't allow me to use html attributes containing hyphens. How can I let Vue convert the CamelCase keys of my Object to kebap-case html attribute names? (Or, speaking of the snippet, get the text to appear in blue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this useful code snippet for your use case

`string
      .replace(/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2')
      .replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z])(?=[a-z])/g, '$1-$2')
      .toLowerCase();`

Reference https://gist.github.com/nblackburn/875e6ff75bc8ce171c758bf75f304707#gistcomment-2874149

This jsfiddle might help you
https://jsfiddle.net/pwmuebnL/

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.